# Use responsive AdsSense unit but only as a banner/rectangle ad?

Tags: google-adsense

I'm using Google AdSense's responsive unit and on load it fits my browser window.

The problem is that AdSense decides to fill the relevant space with both Square and Banner/Rectangle size Ads. I only want Banner size ads.

I've tried putting the Ad in a container that only has a height of 60px but it will still load the square size ads.

How do I tell AdSense I only want Banner/Rectangle size Ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the information given on [this](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893?hl=en) page. I think you are using smart sizing which chooses one of the ad sizes based on the screen size by setting data-ad-format to auto. Try the data-ad-format to "rectangle, horizontal". ( I think it will work but I am not sure. If it doesn't work, try other values. )

> By default, our responsive ad code includes a data-ad-format tag with
>   the value of "auto" which enables the auto-sizing behavior for the
>   responsive ad unit. However, you can set a general shape for your
>   responsive ad unit by changing the value of data-ad-format to one of
>   these values: "rectangle", "vertical", "horizontal" or any combination
>   of these separated by a comma, e.g., "rectangle, horizontal".